NGRX actions with common parameter structure
In angular, I am trying to have a shared error handling mechanism for NgRX effects. I want to have a common interface that all error Actions will implement. For example:
export interface ErrorProperties { error: string };

const createFailed = createAction('[CreateFailed]', props<ErrorProperties>());
const deleteFailed = createAction('[DeleteFailed]', props<ErrorProperties>());

I want to be able to use all of them in a single Effect, like this:
const errorActions: ? = [createFailed, deleteFailed];

handleError = createEffect(() =>
  this._actions.pipe(
    ofType(...errorActions),
    tap((action) => console.log(action.error));
  )
);

I want the effect to have type safety and to recognize that action is guaranteed to have the error property, but I'm not sure what type should errorActions have.

Well, I'd let TypeScript infer the type: const errorActions = [createFailed, deleteFailed]. Is there any specific reason why you need to specify the type? If you access action.error and, by mistake, you pass something that hasn't ErrorProperties in props then TypeScript will show an error

Insite the tap method, action.error is flagged as an error because error isn't a known property of that action. That's what I'm trying to achieve, compile time type safety

I tried your code and it works properly, action.error is correctly recognized as a string. Which version of TypeScript are you using?

Hmm, that is interesting, eventually removing the type from errorActions did in fact trigger IntelliSense and the code compiles fine. I probably had some mistake earlier, but as you say it works as expected. Thanks!

In order for this to have a proper answer, I'll write again the solution below:
export interface ErrorProperties { error: string };

const createFailed = createAction('[CreateFailed]', props<ErrorProperties>());
const deleteFailed = createAction('[DeleteFailed]', props<ErrorProperties>());

And the effect:
const errorActions = [createFailed, deleteFailed];

handleError = createEffect(() =>
  this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType(...errorActions),
    tap(action => console.log(action.error))
  )
)

